# ECMAScript Promise.all method works with jQuery.Deferred. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred, es6-promise

I was making a research for Promises in JavaScript. I'm was interesting can I combine ECMAScript Promises with other implementations, for example jQuery `$.Deferred`. And I was surprised when `Promises.all` works fine with jQuery `$.Deferred`. I'm trying to find the answer in jQuery source code and CommonJS Promises/A specs, but I still misunderstood why this code works as I expected(do `console.log` after 10 seconds, not 5 seconds):

```
var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () { 
        resolve();//resolve first promise after 5 secs
        console.log('Promise resolved');
    }, 5000);
});

var deferred = $.Deferred();
setTimeout(function () { 
    deferred.resolve();//resolve after 10 seconds
    console.log('Deferred resolved');
}, 10000);

Promise.all([promise,deferred]).then(function () {
    console.log('All is done');//log after 10 seconds
});
```

Do you have any ideas?

`Promise.all` must rely on something field or method of `$.Deferred` to understand is resolved it or not. What is that method/field?

Comment: I'm confused as to what exactly you're asking. jQuery's deferred clearly uses the existing promises implementation as its way of achieving the behavior. jQuery is just JavaScript, why is that weird to you?

Comment: You're passing in `deferred`, and even if it isn't a valid promise, its converted to one with `promise.cast`, so it should work either way.

Comment: `Promise.all` must rely on something field or method of `$.Deferred` to understand is resolved it or not. What is that method/field?

Comment: @adeneo in jQuery a `$.Deferred()` has a then method (for whatever reason)

Comment: @Pinal that method or field is `.then` - the concept is `.then`able.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The promises A+ specification (on which the promises unwrapping specification was based on which native promises use) was specifically built to do this.

With a design goal of libraries inter-oping well, the specification is built around a single method: `.then`.

The then method specifies how a continuation of a promise works. jQuery promises expose `.then` since version 1.8 which means they try to participate in this game. While jQuery deferreds and promises are *not* Promises/A+ promises - they attempt to be Promises/A promises which means the following:

```
return Promise.resolve($.get(...))
```

Will always work. A+ promises (and native promises) will assimilate every `.then`able recursively and resolve with its value when you return it.

```
Promise.resolve({then:function(fn){ return fn(3); }}).then(function(el){
    console.log(el); // this logs 3
})
```

If we check the [specification](https://github.com/domenic/promises-unwrapping#promiseall--iterable-) , we can see:

> Let *result* be Invoke(*nextPromise*, `"then"`, (*resolveElement*, *promiseCapability*.[[Reject]])).

(also related is [this](https://github.com/domenic/promises-unwrapping#resolvepromiseviathenabletask--promisetoresolve-thenable-then-))

Which calls `.then` and resolves the next item when that `.then`able resolves

jQuery's deferred uses a nonstandard promise implementation so it cannot consume native promises (That is, you can't predictably `$.when` a native promise. The other way around works.

Comment: _trivia_: this is why the spec was known as `thenables` in the past.